# Output of "for" is unknown instead of 1 in Verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog, iverilog

I'm using Icarus iVerilog to synthesize and test my code but I'm getting unknown values when logically 1's should be appearing. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
reg [8:0] a = 000110100;
wire [8:0] b = 0;

generate
    genvar i;
    for (i = 8; i > -1; i = i - 1)
    begin:loop
        assign b[i] = |a[8:i];
    end
endgenerate
```

This should produce some gates in the form of

```
b[8] = a[8];
b[7] = a[8] | a[7];
b[6] = a[8] | a[7] | a[6];
b[5] = a[8] | a[7] | a[6] | a[5];
...
```

My expected output is

```
000111111
```

I'm actually getting

```
000xxxxxx
```

I can't find any reason for the x's, and am starting to suspect it's an issue with iVerilog.

Comment: Does your synthesis tool support variable declaration initializations?

Comment: I could try this in a different tool tomorrow, but two things you could try for now: 1) use `i>=0` instead of `i>-1`, and 2) count forward from 0 instead of backward from 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please remove assignment in the declaration below. The assign wire to 0 in the declaration makes conflict with assignment 1 in genvar block

```
 wire [8:0] b = 0;
```

change to

```
wire [8:0] b;
```

This is because

```
wire [8:0] b = 0;
```

is not an initialisation, it is a continuous assignment. It is equivalent to

```
wire [8:0] b;
assign b = 0;
```

Hence, the conflict.